# Excel vba: combine multiple files in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 100+ files in one folder. Each file has 3 lists, but only 1 list with data. I need to take that data from each file and combine it in a single file on 1 list. I wrote a sub for it, but I'm not sure how to go around selecting only the range needed (it varies from file to file) - in the same way you do it on keyboard with `Ctrl + Shift + left arrow + down arrow`. And how should I go around pasting it in the result workbook at exactly the first free line after the data that was pasted before?

```
Sub combine()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Dim ExcelApp As Object
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelApp.Visible = False
        ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
        ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        ExcelApp.EnableEvents = False

        '**VARIABLES**
        Dim folderPath As String
        folderPath = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\files\"

        'COUNT THE FILES
        Dim totalFiles As Long
        totalFiles = 0
        Dim fileTitle As String
        fileTitle = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl??")
        Do While fileTitle <> ""
            totalFiles = totalFiles + 1
            fileTitle = Dir()
        Loop

        'OPENING FILES
        Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
        Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
        Set resultWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\result.xlsx")


        fileTitle = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl??")

        'FOR EACH FILE
        Do While fileTitle <> ""
            Set dataWorkbook = ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)
            dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("A1").Select
            dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Selection.CurrentRegion.Select


             `resultWorkbook.Range
             fileTitle = Dir()
         Loop

    ExcelApp.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you create a new application instance inside your current application instance?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie To make it invisible.

Comment: When you talk about a list - do you mean different worksheets, or columns within a single worksheet, or `ListObject`s ?

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie I mean Worksheets by Lists. I have 100+ Workbooks and each has one Worksheet with data.

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood the question and unfortunately I cannot make a comment. If I've grasped this question wrong, i'll delete.

> but I'm not sure how to go around selecting only the range needed

This suggests that you have a dynamic amount of data and want to use `Range` to grab the selections.

Supposing you know the column location of where said data is located (in this case my list starts at B2 and we *don't* know where it ends. You can use `Range` to dynamically select all data:

```
Dim rcell As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
    Debug.Print rcell.Value
Next rcell

End Sub
```

First we define a `Range` variable and assign it to the range starting at B2 and using `.End(xlDown)` we can select a range ending at the final entry.

For further reading on `.End()` see [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Does the `End(xlDown)` immitate `Ctrl+Shift+arrow Down`? How can I given the `End(xlDown)` jumps to the 101th row, copy the range of `"A3:F101"`?

Comment: "*Returns a Range object that represents the cell at the end of the region that contains the source range.*" If you have data which starts at the specified Range and ends at the 101th row, then this code will grab all values. So yes, in a sense :) If you want to get the range `A3:F101` then just specify exactly that: `ActiveSheet.Range("A3:F101").Select`

Comment: Would `Set rng = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))` do the trick?

Comment: 101 was an example. Sometimes it's 101, sometimes it's 64. But it always starts on the 3rd row.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, yes with a bit of tweaking (I haven't tested it myself but I'm sure it would). May I suggest reading the link in my answer and just playing around with it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested your solution and it worked! Any change you know a method for determining the next fresh row to paste data in `resultWorkbook`?

Comment: Great! Off the top of my head: Maybe use .`Offset(0, 1)` and then perform a check to see if the current cell contains a value? Assuming that your data is well structured and always starts at the same row ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150168/discussion-between-daruchini-and-ans).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without VBA. Use Get & Transform instead.
Here are a few steps to get you started:

1. Go to the Data Tab
2. Under Get & Transform, pick New Query - From File - From Folder
3. Select the folder containing all your 100+ files
4. Select the tab that contains your data
5. You are almost there. Do your final fixes (if needed)
6. Once you're done, click Close & Load

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have this Code VBA, its works, i can combine some files on one sheet.
check it!

```
    Sub Open_Files()
Dim Hoja As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'Definir la variable como tipo Variante
   Dim X As Variant
   'Abrir cuadro de dialogo
   X = Application.GetOpenFilename _
       ("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 2, "Abrir archivos", , True)
    'Validar si se seleccionaron archivos
    If IsArray(X) Then ' Si se seleccionan
      'Crea Libro nuevo
       Workbooks.Add
      'Captura nombre de archivo destino donde se grabaran los archivos seleccionados
       A = ActiveWorkbook.Name
      
    '*/********************
   For y = LBound(X) To UBound(X)
   Application.StatusBar = "Importando Archivos: " & X(y)
     Workbooks.Open X(y)
     b = ActiveWorkbook.Name
       For Each Hoja In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Hoja.Copy after:=Workbooks(A).Sheets(Workbooks(A).Sheets.Count)
       Next
       Workbooks(b).Close False
   Next
   Application.StatusBar = "Listo"
   Call Unir_Hojas
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).